# horizontal scroll appears only in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, scrollbar, horizontal-scrolling

I have a problem with horizontal scroll bar appearing in Chrome. The page is 960px wide and the scrollbar shouldn't be active. I can't find an element that causes this issue.

Please help, the site address is http://jciventure.it360.pl/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fault lies with **h1.assistive-text.section-heading**

Change

```
/* Text meant only for screen readers */
.screen-reader-text,
.assistive-text {
    position: absolute !important;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 */
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
}
```

to

```
/* Text meant only for screen readers */
.screen-reader-text,
.assistive-text {
    width:auto;
    position: absolute !important;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 */
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To the main HTML tag on the page include a class with the following:

```
overflow:hidden;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

It'll work in Chrome now.